# The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later

Tags: magento2, php, admin, login, installation

I am trying to log in for the first time and I have unlocked the admin user in cmd with (php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin) I see admin user has been unlocked but when I go back to the login i get the same issue again.

Comment: can you try to use google chrome incognito mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your environment is a development environment and you just want to access the backend, you may create another user, a quick fix is to create a new user:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='yourusername' --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'
```

if it is a production environment, you may want to understand further the issue:
connect to your database, `select * from admin_user where username='<youruser>' limit 1\G`

the above query will show your admin data.[image]

the bottom fields specifically should be identical to the screenshot. So, you may update these fields and then, you should be able to login.

Comment: i created a new account and it worked thank you